# how can I use a non static instance in a static method in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a an instance of lasse1 and  I want to use it in a method of lasse2 , this method is static method, this just doesn't work :

```
 class Lasse2{
 ......
public :
static void function(void);
Lasse1* obj;
........
};
```

And now i want to use it  like :

```
void Lasse2::function(void){
obj->dosmt(); // this doesn't work 
.........
```

any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: You can't.  That's what _static_ means.

Comment: Did you mean `obj` to be static too?

Comment: Must.. resist... cant... *Why* do you *need* to do this?

Comment: this doesn't work, and I can't declarre my obj as static because it use Qt SLOTS and SIGNALS  and when I do this the program crashs

Comment: It might help if you explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Seems like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What do you really want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access an instance member of your class, then you *must* have an instance of that class.  There's no way around this.  Your options are:

1. Make obj a static member.  Do this if you intend to have a single obj for all instances of this class.
2. Remove static from function() so it becomes an instance method.

If you can't do either of those, then you need to find a way to pass an instance pointer to your function.  For example, APIs that require a function pointer often have a mechanism for passing pointer-sized data to that function when it's eventually called.

Answer (score 1):

Change your static method to explicitly pass the object pointer:

```
static void function(Lasse1* obj)
{
    obj->dosmt(); 
}
```

But before you do, consider what you're really trying to do (and even write another question if you like).

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of your class to pull that off.

Create one or receive it through other means (function argument,  global variable, class static variable, etc)

Answer (score 0):

SLaks said it best: "You can't"

Here's why:

When you declare a member variable (not static, see `obj` above), you're telling the compiler that each object of type `Lassie2` contains a pointer to a `Lassie1`.

When you declare a method static, that means that it is independent of all the instances (the actual objects) of that class. It doesn't operate on an object.

So inside of `Lasse2::function`, there's no `this`, no `Lassie2` object for you to get the `obj` pointer from.